# Prettiest way to typeset "C++" (cplusplus)?

Tags: formatting, symbols, kerning

Writing "C++" in plain text results in an ugly setting, as the '+' signs are too big and too spaced:

[image: "C++" in plain text]

I've seen around the web several marcos for typesetting the "C++" symbol, ranging from mild kerning to shrinking, raising and lowering the '+' signs.  What is your version of a `\cpp{}` macro?

Comment: For reasons of completeness: there is a question about this in the C++ FAQs: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-environmental-issues.html#faq-40.2

Comment: Do you mind adding that as an answer? It would be also very useful if you include some code here to copy&paste.

Comment: I'd typeset it as "Cplusplus" :D

Comment: Asked also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724760/how-to-write-c-in-latex

Answer (score 132, accepted):

By general request (or something of the like at least), I made it an answer.

The C++ FAQ mentions this specific problem: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-environmental-issues#latex-macros. The two things they wish to provide are a better typesetting and prevention of line breaks, two possibilities are given:

```
\newcommand{\CC}{C\nolinebreak\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf +}\nolinebreak\hspace{-.10em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf +}}
\def\CC{{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf ++}}}
```

The first one prevents a linebreak, raises the ++'s a little and puts them closer together.

[image: version 1]

The second only prevents a linebreak and raises the ++ a bit.

[image: version 2]

Both options put the ++'s in bold and typeset them a little smaller. Two more are given in the link, but I fail to see why they matter, line break prevention seems *the* must have for such a macro.

Edit: In case you want to use relative sizes you can use the [`relsize` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/relsize/), the code becomes

```
\newcommand\CC{C\nolinebreak\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\relsize{-3}{\textbf{+}}}\nolinebreak\hspace{-.10em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\relsize{-3}{\textbf{+}}}}
\newcommand\CC{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\relsize{-3}{\textbf{++}}}}
```

<strike>I don't have a favourite though, never needed to typeset C++ :).</strike> After experimenting a little, the second one is definitely my favourite, the version with kerning looks too much like the Haskell operator.

Comment: Hmm. Using `\tiny` here isn’t a good idea – what if I want to typeset “C++” in a header or in a footnote?

Comment: @Pieter: the Haskell operator is usually set with a *lot* more overlap (when any is used at all, of course).

Comment: Is there any way to use these commands within a \section{} declaration, eg. \section{\CC Revision}? I keep getting an error message about a brace not matching.

Comment: You'll have to write `\section{\protect\CC Revision}`.

Comment: Pieter, thanks for your tip. It works if I omit the use of the \relsize command. Using \relsize gives the same error as before. Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: I've tested both variants that use `\relsize` and they both work. You have the `relsize` package included?

Comment: Yes, I have included the package. I've just managed to get it to work. My definition is \protected\def\CC{{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\relsize{-3}\bf ++}}} and then I can simply use \section{\CC Revision}. I'm not sure why I cannot get it to work following your suggestion, but you gave me a vital hint about protecting the command. By the way, I also use the \xspace macro at the end of the definition to handle spacing (not shown above). Apologies for the formatting - I am not sure how to markup code in the comments.

Comment: @Steve Markup in comments is like for inline code in answers, i.e. with backticks (``` ).

Comment: Using the `xspace` package and tossing in an `\xspace` at the end might also be helpful.

Comment: As a beginner: How to implement the second approach? Copy-and-paste into body or preamble? Then just type `C++` in body text? Tried this and that, didn't see a difference... MWE, sil vous plait :-)

Comment: This worked in the body text: `C\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf ++}`. How to make it work as a "macro" ?

Comment: Fails with KOMA class, because of `undefined old font command '\bf'`. There is no difference between `\bf` and `\bfseries`, correct? So replacing the bold command solves this

Comment: @Ben: I think the second pair of commands is meant to solve the `undefined old font command '\bf'` (at least it did for me). So this is the usecase the author of the answer was wondering about.

Comment: These definitions seem to fail when used in captions.

Comment: First one looks great.

Answer (score 113):

Personally, I like the look of `C\texttt{++}` the best.  It's also very simple!

[image: C++]

Comment: Follows the KISS principle. +1

Answer (score 23):

Here's how C++ is typeset in the C++ standard:

```
\newcommand{\Rplus}{\protect\hspace{-.1em}\protect\raisebox{.35ex}{\smaller{\smaller\textbf{+}}}}
\newcommand{\Cpp}{\mbox{C\Rplus\Rplus}\xspace}
```

That looks like this:

[image]

Comment: ... and `\smaller` is provided by `relzise` package.

Comment: ... and `\xspace` is provided by the `xspace` package. That said, `\xspace` introduces its own set of problems and it may be wise to avoid it.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I think that you meant the `relsize` package (rather than `relzise`)

Answer (score 11):

I’ve previously used the following definition (using `\scalebox` from the `graphicx` package):

```
\newcommand*\cpp{C\kern-0.2ex\raisebox{0.4ex}{\scalebox{0.8}{+\kern-0.4ex+}}}
```

[image: C++]

Note that it doesn’t do some things that Pieter’s solution does, in particular it doesn’t prevent a line break (is this even possible here?) – but this could be amended easily by putting it into an `\mbox`. I’ve also modified the kerning to make the two plusses merge into one. Whether this looks good somewhat depends on the font, though.

In hindsight, the plusses are too high for my taste.

Answer (score 9):

Another "correct" way is to use [the `texlogos` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/texlogos), which defines the C++ logo as:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cpluspluslogo}{\hbox{C\hspace{-0.5ex}
                       \protect\raisebox{0.5ex}
                       {\protect\scalebox{0.67}{++}}}}
```

[image]

That said, I do prefer the appearance shown in other posts, particularly Pieter's second.

Comment: +1 for the correctness. Not very good looking though.

Answer (score 6):

I think it depends quite a bit on the font you use.  I just tried the recommended macros with Lucida Bright, and in general the +'s were way too small and way too high. I got a reasonable result with the macros recommended in the C++ FAQ, but replacing `\tiny` by `\small` and raising the boxes only `.2ex` instead of `.4ex`.  I suggest you experiment with your font.

Comment: But having to think about font is very unLatex.
(It goes against the whole Content without worry of formatting)

Comment: In my experience there is nothing that can be done about this. It does depend on the font how high the ++ has to go. To the best of my knowledge there is no way to extract this knowledge somehow. Using the x-height is already the best you can do but it still depends on the shape of the 'C'.

Comment: @Oxinabox -- logos aren't to be considered "traditional typography" -- they're often custom designed (even perhaps more often than not; the latex logo itself is not font-neutral). therefore, assuming that they're "automatic" in latex isn't appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

I liked @kundors solution, but modified it so that `C` and `+` uses the same font and has the same weight. Here you can see the difference and decide your self:

```
C\texttt{++} \texttt{C++}
```

[image: C++]

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't specifically ask for LaTeX, yet all answers so far are in LaTeX, none in TeX. My solution, which, of course, you can put into a `\def` or simply straight into the text if you only need it once:

`C\raise .8ex \hbox{$_{++}$}`

Assuming 10pt size of the font; the '++' is in script style, which is size 7. Would it be better to use scriptscript style, having something like the following?

`C\raise ??? \hbox{$_{_{++}}$}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2):

I found that the suggestion from the C++ FAQ looks bad in many contexts. So I abused inline math to build something that also looks good in titles etc.:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\CC}[1][]{$\text{C\hspace{-.25ex}}^{_{_{_{++}}}}
                      \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\text{\hspace{-.625ex}#1}}$}
```

This takes the standard version as an optional argument:
**\CC** typesets C++, **\CC[17]** typesets C++17.

The following shot demonstrates \CC[14] and \CC in context:

[image]

Comment: The `++`  is much too small for my taste.

Answer (score 2):

Another in the string of correct ways is to use the [Middlescript macros by V. Eijkhout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250961/subscript-superscript-middlescript), which adjusts to the font centerline and covers size changes pretty well (about as well as standard subscript and superscript). I won't copypaste the macro code since it's just a SE link, but with it you can use:

```
C\textmidscript{++}         % text-mode
$\mathrm{C\midscript{++}}$  % math-mode
```

Answer (score 1):

After much effort, I finally landed on the following macro:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{xspace}
% ...
\newcommand{\Cpp}{\texorpdfstring{\mbox{C\raisebox{.35ex}{\textsmaller[2]{++}}}\xspace}{C++}}
```

Unlike the other answers here, it uses `\texorpdfstring` to avoid issues with hyperlinks and tables of contents. I also found that `\relsize{-3}` was broken somehow on TeXLive 2022 (at least on Overleaf), so I use `\textsmaller[2]` instead. Shrinking by 2 instead of 3 looked better in my document, but YMMV.

---

Demonstration:

[image: demonstration of typesetting macro for "C++"]

Comment: You forgot to add the use of `hyperref`.

Comment: You should test `\texttt{\Cpp}` and `\textsf{\Cpp\}.

Comment: @projetmbc - Added `hyperref`, thanks. I just tested `\texttt{\Cpp}` and `\textsf{\Cpp}` and they look reasonable. Just `\texttt{\mbox{C++}}` is probably better than `\texttt{\Cpp}`, though.