# How to make the correct hash-symbol in C Sharp (C#)

Tags: symbols

I want to make `C#` look nice in my book, but with the following:

`C\#` it looks like this:

[image]

When it should look more like this:

[image]

For the second one, I used verbatim, but I don't want that and I've also used a macro like the following everywhere so it should be easy to replace:

`\def\Csharp{C\#}`

Any suggestions on how I make this look correct?

**Edit**

I am writing a programming book, in the C# Language Specification, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Use `\texttt{C\#}` for your second picture. And you'll find this question useful: [Prettiest way to typeset “C++”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/prettiest-way-to-typeset-c)

Comment: If it's about music, `\newcommand{\textsharp}{$\sharp$}`

Comment: It's about programming, I've never seen the music-style on it before though.

Comment: So it's not the note symbol and the question title should reflect this.

Comment: I thought it was, I'll change the title.

Comment: Don't use `\texttt{C\#}`. 'C' must be set in the normal font.

Comment: Perhaps `\newcommand{\csharp}{C\raisebox{.8ex}{\scriptsize\#}}`? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, It does look exactly like the title page for the C# Language Specification, but it doesn't look good in normal paragraphs unfortunately. Maybe the `#` needs to be aligned with the C instead.

Comment: How about this? \newcommand{\csharp}{C$^\#$}

Comment: Oops, sorry, should have read your comment first. Mine looks exactly like Paulo's. Note that you can adjust that `.8ex` in Paulo's comment to adjust the height. 0.5 gets it pretty close to level with the top of the C.

Comment: My opinion is that you should not fiddle with the symbol placement, because it will disrupt the read flow. Instead you should find/create a good-looking hash symbol that will not stand out. While most popular fonts have such a symbol, Computer Modern Roman/Sans Serif, unfortunately, does not.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov, Agreed, do you have an example perhaps to make it look good?

Comment: @FilipEkberg Actually, it should be a sharp symbol as in a musical sharp note, it was intended to be this way, the only reason for a hash symbol can be summed up in ASCII. I believe some modern books use the originally intended musical sharp character.

Comment: @egreg Your solution is correct either-way.

Comment: @AymanElmasry: Indeed! Wikipedia says that the original intent was the musical symbol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Name

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since Computer Modern Roman does not have a fitting hash symbol, we need to look somewhere else. I experimented with several popular fonts and found that the hash symbol from Liberation Serif does not stand out, has approximately the same brush width and isn't too wide.

[image: Result]

Unfortunately, as Liberation Serif is a TrueType font, it can't be readily used with pdfTeX. Below is the code to use it with XeTeX/LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface\lserif{Liberation Serif}

\newcommand{\Csh}{C{\lserif\#}}

\begin{document}

Some text \Csh{} some text.

\end{document}
```

### Workaround for pdfTeX

Process this file with XeTeX/LuaTeX and save the result as `hash-symbol.pdf`:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}% I get extra space without this comment
\fontspec{Liberation Serif}\#
\end{document}
```

Then use this code to include the symbol with pdfTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\Csh}{C\includegraphics{hash-symbol}}

\begin{document}

Some text \Csh{} some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The positioning of the symbol might be slightly off, use `\kern` and `\raisebox` to fine-tune. Also note that this will only work for one font size; to remedy this, `\scalebox` might be useful ([manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf)).

Comment: It's a nice start, I need it to work with pdfText though, maybe someone else has some ideas on this too. Thanks!

Comment: @Filip You might consider switching anyway. While pdfTeX has served well, I would say that we might soon start to call it obsolete. Modern TeX implementations are simply superior in so many regards.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, pdflatex was what came with texlive/texniccenter. You're saying I should upgrade to something else?

Comment: @Filip TeXnicCenter is an editor (and a pretty crappy one at that, speak Unicode support). TeXLive and other distributions all ship with modern TeX renderers (XeTeX, LuaTeX, ConTeXt).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I wouldn't lump in ConTeXt with XeTeX and LuaTeX. ConTeXt is - like LaTeX - a macro package that sits on top of TeX while XeTeX and LuaTeX are implementations of TeX itself

Comment: @FilipEkberg: I updated the answer with a workaround for pdfTeX.

Comment: @kahen True, my mistake.

Comment: Only problem is that it will not be searchable nor will it by possible to copy/paste it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I don't want a TeX reader, I need it to produce a PDF for me to upload for publishing on CreateSpace, they take either PDF or Word Doc.

Comment: @Filip Not sure what you mean by that. All the modern processors produce PDFs.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I thought that was what pdfLatex was doing, producing the PDF?

Comment: @Filip So does XeTeX (command `xetex` or `xelatex`) or LuaTeX (no idea what the commands are called, never used it yet …).

Comment: I'm on Windows, don't know if that came with the installation for TexLive, have to check it out later.

Comment: @FilipEkberg: Did you try it at all? I can search for and copy `C#` in Evince.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov, How is that possible when it's an image and not text? No I haven't tried because I don't have XeTeX (as far as I know anyways)

Comment: @FilipEkberg: It's text! Including a PDF does not mean converting it to an image. And you probably have XeTeX installed or easily available, you need to do a bit of research on how to use it.

Comment: Ok. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 45):

Like egreg said earlier in his comment, use `\newcommand{\textsharp}{$\sharp$}`

The hash symbol was used out of necessity since ASCII did not contain a sharp symbol, but it was intended as a sharp note symbol as the language name denotes.

Addendum: You could always use `$^\sharp$` for superscript.

[image]

Comment: Yup! That’s why it’s called “C Sharp” and not “C Pound Sign” or “C Octothorpe”.

Comment: Both the C# language specification and the LaTeX paper on C# I'm citing (Variance and Generalized Constraints for C♯ Generics) use a superscript, and $^\sharp$ is the closest I can get.

Answer (score 25):

You might do with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\Csharp}{%
  {\settoheight{\dimen0}{C}C\kern-.05em \resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{\raisebox{\depth}{\#}}}}
\begin{document}
\Huge\Csharp
\end{document}
```

Here's the result; the second line has `\fontseries{b}\selectfont\#`, but the strokes seem to be too heavy:

[image]

If you prefer to use the music sharp symbol, it might be

```
\newcommand{\Csharp}{%
  {\settoheight{\dimen0}{C}C\kern-.05em \resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{\raisebox{\depth}{$\sharp$}}}}
```

[image]

Comment: When I try this, I find that I have to manually insert a space by typing \, after \Csharp.  The result doesn't look quite right. Could you modify your MWE to use \Csharp in the middle of a sentence?

Comment: @littleO Like every LaTeX command, it ”eats“ spaces after it. Use ”backslash space“ or {}

Comment: Oh ok, thank you. I actually didn't realize I could just use "backslash space" to make a smaller space than I get with \,. This answer was really useful to me!

Answer (score 6):

If you use **XeTeX** and your font supports it, you can put the Unicode character directly into your source file, or use `\symbol{"266F}`. With fonts such as **[Linux Libertine](http://www.linuxlibertine.org/)**, this looks much nicer than `\sharp`, which seems to use raw TeX rather than looking for a proper sharp character:

[image: Screenshot of different methods of rendering C# using XeTeX]

Comment: You can get a better-matched sharp symbol in Libertine if you add `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` and then use `$\sharp$`.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44537/3714) and looking at the C# language specification (a .docx...) I came up with this:

```
\newcommand{\csharp}{C\nolinebreak[4]\raisebox{.6ex}{\includegraphics[scale=.8]{hash-symbol}}}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: 1]

Note that when using LuaLaTex you'll need to add `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` to the top of the file that you use for generating the PDF due to compatibility issues with the `standalone` document class. Also note that the Liberation fonts can be found here: https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}% I get extra space without this comment
\fontspec{Liberation Serif}\#
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do I get the hash-symbol image?  Can you give a MWE?

Comment: Added MWE. Run that through `pdflatex` and you should get the PDF. You can use PDF files as images, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: If you're using lualatex (and I assume also xelatex), you don't need the external document; you can just use `graphicx`'s `scalebox`.

Answer (score 5):

Here’s a version using `\ooalign` to combine an equal sign with two tightly kerned slashes.  It works for all 10 standard sizes from `\tiny` up to `\Huge`.

[image: examples]

**The Good**

- The line stroke widths are consistent and feel right (to me).

**The Bad**

- As you can see from the code below, it’s rather a bit of a hack. I’m sure there are probably more elegant ways to do this. Perhaps someone can improve it and post a follow-up.
- You may need to tweak the positioning parameters if you’re using non-CMR or non-LMR fonts.
- The reason the implentation is so complicated is because the regular slash character is too tall for this, necessitating the use of a smaller sized slash in each case.  Everything above `\footnotesize` uses a smaller slash; the smallest three make do with their respective native slashes.

**The Ugly**

- Because of calculation rounding issues, the display of this may not look quite right on screen; you may notice the // and the = appearing to be 1 pixel out of alignment in an on-screen PDF viewer at low dpi.  It should be fine in print, however.  This problem is common with many hand-composited symbols like this one.

Here’s the code with an (almost) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\Csharp@tiny{5}
\def\Csharp@scriptsize{7}
\def\Csharp@footnotesize{8}
\def\Csharp@small{9}
\def\Csharp@normalsize{10}
\def\Csharp@large{12}
\def\Csharp@Large{14.4}
\def\Csharp@LARGE{17.28}
\def\Csharp@huge{20.74}
\def\Csharp@Huge{24.88}
\newcommand{\Csharp}{%
  \mbox{%
    C%
    \ooalign{%
      \noalign{%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@tiny\vskip-1.11ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@scriptsize\vskip-1.11ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@footnotesize\vskip-1.07ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@small\vskip-1.07ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@normalsize\vskip-1.07ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@large\vskip-1.07ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@Large\vskip-1.07ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@LARGE\vskip-1.07ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@huge\vskip-1.07ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@Huge\vskip-1.07ex\fi%
      }%
      \hss{=}\hss\cr%
      \noalign{%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@tiny\vskip-0ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@scriptsize\vskip-0ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@footnotesize\vskip-0ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@small\vskip-.06ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@normalsize\vskip-.10ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@large\vskip-.10ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@Large\vskip-.10ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@LARGE\vskip-.10ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@huge\vskip-.10ex\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@Huge\vskip-.10ex\fi%
      }%
      \hss{%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@tiny\tiny\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@scriptsize\scriptsize\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@footnotesize\footnotesize\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@small\footnotesize\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@normalsize\footnotesize\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@large\normalsize\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@Large\large\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@LARGE\Large\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@huge\LARGE\fi%
        \ifx\f@size\Csharp@Huge\huge\fi%
        {/}\kern-.26em{/}%
      }\hss\cr%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\emergencystretch=2em
\narrower\narrower\narrower\narrower\narrower\narrower\narrower
\noindent\Csharp\ (pronounced ``see sharp'') is a multi-paradigm programming language
encompassing strong typing, imperative, declarative, functional, generic,
object-oriented (class-based), and component-oriented programming disciplines.
\vskip 1em
\noindent\tiny\Csharp\,
\scriptsize\Csharp\,
\footnotesize\Csharp\,
\small\Csharp\,
\normalsize\Csharp\par\vskip-.25em
\noindent\large\Csharp\,
\Large\Csharp\,
\LARGE\Csharp\par\vskip-.25em
\noindent\huge\Csharp\,
\Huge\Csharp\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Defining those sizes seems pointless. The LaTeX kernel defines them as: `\@vpt, \@viipt, \@viiipt, \@ixpt, \@xpt, \@xiipt, \@xivpt, \@xviipt, \@xxpt, \@xvpt` and I don't think anything ever modifies them (because that would be *crazy*)

Answer (score 4):

Using TikZ it's possible to draw the desired symbol manually:

```
\def\Csharp{C\tikz[x=1em,y=\baselineskip]%
  \draw (0.125,0.15) -- ++(0.15,0.5)%
        (0.325,0.15) -- ++(0.15,0.5)%
        (0.05,0.3) -- ++(0.45,0.0)%
        (0.1,0.5) -- ++(0.45,0.0);}
```

This has some issues though. For example the symbol doesn't scale all that well with changing font size, but the difference between `\Large` and `\normalsize` isn't too bad.  Additionally it's impossible to copy "C#" from the resulting PDF file into the clipboard which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: Copying is somewhat possible: overlay the drawing on a zero-sized white `\#`.

Answer (score 4):

For pfdtex I prefere:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\Csharp}{%
  {\settoheight{\dimen0}{C}C\kern-.05em \resizebox{!}{\dimen0}{\raisebox{\depth}{\textbf{\#}}}}}
\begin{document}
\Huge\Csharp
\end{document}
```

Similar to the above but with thick `#`, because the thin one does not fit to the `C` in my eyes.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I take a `\#` and, in superscript mode, make it the same vertical footprint as `ig`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\myhash{$^{\scalerel*{\#}{ig}}$}
\begin{document}
C\myhash
\end{document}
```

[image]

The even simpler `C\scalerel*{\#}{X}` typesets as

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try `C\verb|#|`, if this form suits your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

How about these?

`\def\CSH{{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\footnotesize\bf \#}}}`

A direct variation of [Prettiest way to typeset "C++" (cplusplus)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/prettiest-way-to-typeset-c-cplusplus)