# How to Typeset C# with pdfTeX?

Tags: typography

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make the correct hash-symbol in C Sharp (C#)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/how-to-make-the-correct-hash-symbol-in-c-sharp-c)

What is the best way to typeset C# using pdfTeX?

At the moment I'm using `C\#` but that does not look nice.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The suggested solution is not based on pdftex.

Comment: I posted my preferred solution in the question marked as duplicate.