# Making “C♯” on my resume searchable

Tags: symbols, pdf, luatex, copy-paste

As discussed on [How to make the correct hash-symbol in C Sharp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/how-to-make-the-correct-hash-symbol-in-c-sharp-c), I chose to render the name of the C# language on my resume as `C$^\sharp$`

[image]

I'd like to keep that typographical touch. But I'm afraid that will make it impossible for automated tools to spot “C#” in my resume.

Is there a way to print C# with a sharp(♯) but have it behave as a hash(#) as far as the find and copy-paste features of a PDF reader are concerned?

I'm using LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The more common problem is likely to be that PotentialNewJobCo's HR dept is still using DerpSoft ResumeScraperPro 2005 which unable to extract data from anything that isn't a .doc file and will puke on the pdf just as totally as if you sent them raw tex.

Answer (score 43):

The PDF format knows a feature "ActualText" that allows to specify a replacement string for copy/paste:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand*{\Csharp}{%
  C%
  \BeginAccSupp{
    method=hex,
    unicode=false,
    ActualText=23,
  }%
  $^\sharp$%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
}
\begin{document}
\Csharp
\end{document}
```

The feature is supported by AcrobatReader, but there are other PDF viewers without supporting it.

Comment: Works as expected in (at least) Evince 3.8.3 and Acrobat 9.4.1 (Linux), (the text 'C#' is copied).

Comment: Does it make any difference whether I specify the `#` your way or with `method=plain, ActualText={\#}`? The latter seems to be more easily understandable as source code. (Works with AR, doesn’t work with SumatraPDF and PDF-XChange Viewer.) And is there a reason you’re using the starred version of `\newcommand`? The new macro doesn’t even take an argument here.

Comment: @doncherry, it works in the viewers I reported earlier. (and also in zathura 0.2.3 and poppler's `pdftotext`)

Comment: @doncherry: `\#` cannot be used, because it is not expandable and does not expand to a plain `#`. `\ltx@hashchar` of package `ltxcmds` could be used. But that needs `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. A naked `#` causes much trouble because of its catcode as parameter character. Thus, IMHO, `method=hex` is the easiest method for this case.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I don’t fully understand expansion, but it does seem to me like `\#` works – I can search for and copy the `#` in the pdf just fine.

Comment: what about \begingroup\catcode`#=12 #\catcode`#=6\endgroup?

Comment: @doncherry: It's sheer luck. In LaTeX `\#` is defined via `\chardef` and therefore it is not expanded, but written as the two bytes `\` and `#`. Then the PDF viewer ignores the backslash, because it does not escape anything with a special meaning. Using non-obvious side effects in both TeX and the PDF format is not my understanding of "plain".

Comment: @Francis: Changing the catcode of `#` allows a clean specification of `ActualText=#` with `method=plain`. However, the code for the catcode change(s) makes the code less readable. Therefore I decided to stick to `method=hex`.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a hack that uses `\ooalign` and `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\Chash}{\ooalign{\hidewidth\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=0]{C\#};\cr C$^\sharp$ \cr}}

\begin{document}
I know \Chash and else.
\end{document}
```

**Explain**: `\ooalign` put a transparent `C\#` over `C$^\sharp$` such that you can find it in the PDF. I believe this one does not depend on what PDF viewer you're using.

[image]

**Update**:
Replacing `\#` with plain #, this can break `\newcommand` if you forget to switch the catcode back to 6:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\catcode`#=12
\newcommand{\Chash}{\ooalign{\hidewidth\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=0]{C#};\cr C$^\sharp$ \cr}}
\catcode`#=6

\begin{document}
I know \Chash and else.
\end{document}
```

Search in PDF:

[image]