# Make icon fonts in PDF searchable by name

Tags: luatex, pdf, embedding, accessibility

Nowadays, icon fonts are quite popular on the web. There have been `latex` bindings to these icon fonts through packages such as [`academicons`](https://ctan.org/pkg/academicons), [`fontawesome5`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) and [`fontmfizz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontmfizz).

This brings in new possibilities such as using them on documents such as resumes to indicate computing-related skills.  While being visually pleasing, there are two issues with them

- The words extracted from the PDF by an Applicant Tracking System (ATS) eg. by using a `pdftotext` is non-parseable
- More importantly, even if a human recruiter manually reads the PDF of the CV, they won't be able to search for any keywords for job descriptions currently handled by them.

This renders the entire skills section nearly useless and running the risk of a suitable applicant not making it to the interview stage, diminshing the value of icon fonts to mere eye candy.

I think embedding an `alt-text` is a great workaround for such cases for which I tried the solutions proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132846/making-c%E2%99%AF-on-my-resume-searchable)

However, weirdly the first solution there using `accsupp` package only works with `adobe reader` while the second solution works only with `sumatrapdf` or other `mupdf` based readers. But both these methods highlight a far greater rectangular area than that corresponding to the searched icon.

My question is *Is there a way to combine both these methods into a single solution*? I am happy to accept a `luatex` solution if needed. I know there is no perfect solution, but is there any alternative to this approach that is viewer agnostic?

Here is a `MWE`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontmfizz}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\archlinux}{\ooalign{\hidewidth\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=0]{Linux};\cr \mfArchlinux \cr}}

\begin{document}
I know \Huge \archlinux.
\end{document}
```

The solution needs to be `case-insensitive` e.g. here, when searching for either `linux` or `Linux`, we need to always find the match/highlight the icon in the PDF.

#### PS:

Another useful reference [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/need-alt-text-for-images-in-pdf-for-screen-readers) for this situation.

#### Update:

The `tikz` based solution in the [original link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132846/making-c%E2%99%AF-on-my-resume-searchable) works in `mupdf` based readers,  but weirdly in `adobereader` only the single letter `l` or `L` is matched. Upon entering the next character `li`, the search stops matching. Totally weird.

Comment: With your code I can find `linux` using Okular. Perhaps this is viewer dependent... The case sensitiveness is. Okular has a toggle to switch that on and off.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I know there is no perfect solution, but is there an alternative to this approach that is viewer agnostic?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It works on `sumatrapdf` (a `mupdf` reader) for me, but does not work in `adobereader` which is the reference reader for the `pdf` standard (and the most widely used one, particularly by people outside academia). It is most likely that a recruiter is on Windows/AdobeReader combo just searching a PDF for some keywords.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know. But usually things seems to work better/be implemented first for Adobe Reader. Have your tried the `accsupp` package, using `ActualText` or `E`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  I am unable to understand that `ActualText` answer. I shall much appreciate it if you can try it out and post an answer if it works for you?

Comment: ActualText (with accsupp or tagpdf) is the method recommended in the pdf reference, but as you discovered not every viewer handles this correctly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Can we try to combine these two solutions somehow? The `actualtext` solution works flawlessly with `adobereader` while the `tikz` solution works only with `mupdf`-based readers. I am convinced that  combining the two is the key!

Comment: @Krishna Ooh, Ulrike was faster :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine both answers like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontmfizz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\newcommand{\archlinux}{%
 \BeginAccSupp{
    method=plain,
    unicode=false,
    ActualText=Linux,
  }%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=0]{Linux};\cr \mfArchlinux \cr}%
  \EndAccSupp{}%
  }
\begin{document}

I know \Huge \archlinux.

\end{document}
```

An alternative is

```
\newcommand{\archlinux}{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=0]{Linux};\cr 
   \BeginAccSupp{
    method=plain,
    unicode=false,
    ActualText=Linux,
  }%
\mfArchlinux\EndAccSupp{}\cr}%
  %
  }
```

But copy and paste is a bit curious:

```
ILknionw ux Linux. 1
1
```

Imho it is better to make the word so small that adobe don't get confused about the reading order. This here works with sumatra and adobe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontmfizz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\archlinux}{%
 \tikz[overlay]\node[opacity=0,font=\tiny]{Linux};\mfArchlinux}%
\begin{document}

I know \Huge \archlinux.


\end{document}
```

And it copy&paste better: I know Linux �.

Comment: that gives an error `\ACCSUPP@bdc ->\pdfliteral \ACCSUPP@pdfliteral {\ACCSUPP@span BDC} l.16 I know \Huge \archlinux . The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. ! Undefined control sequence. \ACCSUPP@emc ->\pdfliteral \ACCSUPP@pdfliteral {EMC} l.16 I know \Huge \archlinux`

Comment: Then your accsupp is probably not up-to-date.

Comment: @UrikeFischer got it. Overleaf is the culprit. They are still on TL2016. I shall try it out tomorrow and report back.

Comment: I added a third possibility without accsupp.

Comment: The third possibility is 99% there. But, may I push a little bit further if that's okay with you?  when doing ` pdftotext.exe -layout main.pdf`, the resulting text file is a bit mangled `I know .
     Linux




             1`  with some crazy series of linebreaks/incorrect ordering and weird characters (none of which are rendered in this comment unfortunately), but please try for yourself. Why is this happening? What can be done to improve the situation?

Comment: the reading order in a pdf is not well defined if the pdf has not been tagged, the viewers guess the order of chars when copying  -- and if the pdf has been  tagged you need a viewer which understands tagging to benefit from it. If you want a really accessible format, don't use pdf. Sent a html or a docx or a odt.

Comment: alright. No problems. So this is the best we can do, right? You have an experimental tagging package, right? Any chance we could apply that?

Comment: You can try. tagpdf is on ctan. But at first tagging is not  local code: if you tag you must tag the whole document, and at second you need a pdf viewer which understands and uses the tagging code.

Comment: alright. I give up. I don't want to do global tagging. Just want to tag the local icon font's overlay.  Would you consider a feature request in the package repo for local tagging (in the future, of course)?

Comment: that's not possible, that a restriction of the pdf format.