# Inserting the "incomparability" symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I tried to insert the "is incomparable to" (or "equal and parallel to") symbol [image]to my equation. So, I tried the solution supplied by Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#cite_note-19). But I got a compiler error (missing $ inserted)

Any comment, suggestion is welcome
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `\#` or `\text{\#}` (with `\usepackage{amsmath}`)?

Comment: Math symbols need to be in math mode, $...$.  You might also enjoy https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/

Comment: I tried with \# and \text{\#} but this is not the exact symbol I am looking for. I edited my post and put an image of the symbol that I want. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44528/15925

Comment: You can try `\equalparallel`; see the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol LIst](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (Table 103, p 57).