# A package with macros for programming languages names?

Tags: packages

Is there any package with predefined macros for common programming languages' names? I mean, macros that help writing things like C++, C#, F# etc. in a nice way, the same way as for example \TeX? I have already written some of my own macros to do that but surely someone else has already thought about that and have prepared such useful macros in a package.

EDIT:
Here are macros that I use myself. Might be useful for someone else.

```
\newcommand{\CPP}{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.3ex}{\small++}\xspace}
\newcommand{\CS}{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.2ex}{\small\#}\xspace}
\newcommand{\FS}{F\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.2ex}{\small\#}\xspace}
```

Comment: For `C++`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/prettiest-way-to-typeset-c

Comment: @tohecz thanks, though I knew about that discussion. In fact, the question came to my mind when I read that.

Comment: Instead of using `\nolinebreak`, put the whole code in `\hbox{...}`

Comment: for TeX Logos there's `hologo` or `metalogo`

Comment: @tohecz thanks for the tip. I have never used \hbox before. It seems that something simple such as \hbox{C++} does not always work. I'll need to study it a bit more.

Comment: @tohecz Better `\mbox`, as `\hbox` doesn't start a paragraph if found in vertical mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the answers to [Prettiest way to typeset "C++" (cplusplus)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4302/prettiest-way-to-typeset-c) show, there is no general consensus on how to typeset those fancy names. There's no package for them either.

Thus you're better using your definitions, probably written in a more context independent way; for instance your

```
\newcommand{\CPP}{C\nolinebreak[4]\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.3ex}{\small++}\xspace}
```

will give wrong results if used in a section title that's typeset at a larger size, because `\small` is hard coded:

[image]

You can do better with the `relsize` package or, as the scaling you require is not very big, with `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace,graphicx}
\newcommand{\CPP}{C\kern-.05em \raisebox{.3ex}{\scalebox{.9}{++}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

{\Large\texttt{\string\Large} size: \CPP\par}

\texttt{normal} size: \CPP\par

{\small\texttt{\string\small} size: \CPP\par}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in the following image, the font size is respected.

[image]

Using `\kern-.05em` instead of `\hspace{-.05em}` ensures that no break point is inserted between the C and the two plus signs. Alternatively

```
\newcommand{\CPP}{\mbox{C\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.3ex}{\scalebox{.9}{++}}}\xspace}
```

will do the same.

You can do similarly for `\CS` and `\FS`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I also realized that there is no standard way to typeset the names for these languages. I liked your solution as mine was definitely broken.