# How to outputs 'C\C++'

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I just try output *C\C++* in LaTeX as following below:

```
\textit{C\backslashC\+\+}
```

But im getting this issue:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> C\backslashC 
                    \+\+
l.141 ... \textit{C\backslashC\+\+}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class

\begin{document}
I love \texttt{C/C++} but not \texttt{C\char`\\ C++}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: style of backslash is different from that of forward slash.  in `\texttt`, use this: `\char\\ ` (and better yet, put an open quote before the double backslash, but that's real hard to show as a literal in this markdown environment).

Comment: ``\char`\\`` (backtick backtick slash char backtick slash slash backtick backtick) is possible as a markdown.

Comment: thanks.  i'm trying to do this on an ipad, and it doesn't like to do what I tell it at the best of times.  anyhow, your example looks much better now.

Comment: It may be helpful to explain why the OP's code did not work, or (perhaps more reasonable) point to a resource that does.

Answer (score 6):

The error message says that `\backslashC` is undefined. You need to put something between the command and the `C` so LateX can see you want `\backslash` followed by a `C`. You can use a space (ignored after a command name) or a brace group: `\backslash{}C`. Once that error is past, you will get several more errors: `\backslash` is a mathmode command, and `\+` is undefined. What you want is something like `\textit{C$\backslash$C++}`, but the spacing is all wrong. Also, one usually uses a forward slash in combinations like this. Here are two possibilities, one using a backslash (with the spacing improved) and one with a forward slash:

```
\textit{C$\,\backslash\!$C++}
\textit{C/C++}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining [Donut E. Knot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146955/7880) with [Prettiest way to typeset “C++” (cplusplus)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4302/7880) gives the following answer:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class

\newcommand{\CC}{C\nolinebreak\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf +}\nolinebreak\hspace{-.10em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf +}}

\begin{document}
I love \texttt{C/\CC} but not \texttt{C\char`\\ \CC}.
\end{document}
```

[image: I love C/C ++ but not C\C++]

Via [The Endevor](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/10/18/typesetting-c-in-latex/)

I have no idea why the original posters code does not work.

Comment: Because `\backslashC` is undefined control sequence as the error message aptly says :)