# Remove white spaces from latex

Tags: formatting, pdftex, pdf

How can the white spaces from the output of the following line:

```
$C++$
```

be omitted so that there is no white space between **'C'** and **'+'** and the last **'+'**.

The current output is:

```
C + +
```

C and the pluses are considered operands and operators.

Comment: Wrap each in a set of `{} `, + have special meaning in math

Comment: Related: [How to outputs 'C\C++'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146949/5764)