# Subscript. Superscript. Middlescript?

Tags: positioning

What's the best way to vertically center inline text for both math and text modes?

Is there something similar to `\textsuperscript` for non-math mode?

Comment: In math mode you have `\vcenter{\hbox{..}}` in text mode you have `\raisebox{\dimexpr\depth-.5\totalheight+\fontdimen22\textfont2\relax}{..}` (this one is from memory, I can't test it right now). Let's hope in the future `\vcenter` is extended into text-mode so we do not need to play with this kind of things…

Comment: @Manuel There's `\textvcenter` in TeX by Topic (12.6.8): `\def\textvcenter{\hbox \bgroup$\everyvbox{\everyvbox{}\aftergroup$\aftergroup\egroup}\vcenter}`

Comment: @egreg Magicians existed long before I came to this TeX world, I see.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I found the [TeX by Topic](http://www.math.ecnu.edu.cn/~latex/docs/Eng_doc/TeX_Topic.pdf "http://www.math.ecnu.edu.cn/~latex/docs/Eng_doc/TeX_Topic.pdf") resource, but my ignorance is limiting my ability to implement @egreg's solution. Do I just use `\textvcenter{lipsum}`? Is this built in, or do I need to define this macro in the preamble? I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: After you add the definition that egreg posted you use it like the math mode one basically `\textvcenter{\hbox{lipsum}}`.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks for the clarification. This is exactly what I needed. Now I just wonder why this isn't a standard definition. Also, impressive memory re your first comment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a good occasion for illustrating a macro by Victor Eijkhout, that can be found in TeX by Topic, section 12.6.8; the advantage over directly using `\vcenter` is that `\setbox<number>=\xvcenter{...}` is possible.

The `\midscript` macro chooses a smaller size in (first level) subscripts or superscripts. It won't give good results in second level ones.

```
\documentclass{article}

% macro by V. Eijkhout in TeX by Topic
\makeatletter
\protected\def\xvcenter{%
  \hbox\bgroup$\everyvbox{\everyvbox{}\aftergroup\m@th\aftergroup$\aftergroup\egroup}%
  \vcenter
}
% The \everyvbox token list will be executed
% just after the { that follows \vcenter;
% the closing } will trigger the three \aftergroup tokens
% so $ will balance the formula started in the outer \hbox
% and \egroup will close it.
% I added to Eijkhout's macro also \m@th to neutralize the
% \mathsurround and \protected, just to be on the safe side.

\DeclareRobustCommand{\midscript}[1]{
  \mathchoice{\mid@script\scriptstyle{#1}}
    {\mid@script\scriptstyle{#1}}
    {\mid@script\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}
    {\mid@script\scriptscriptstyle{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\mid@script}[2]{
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th#1#2$}}
}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\textmidscript}[1]{%
  \xvcenter{\hbox{\scriptsize#1}}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$x^{a}$  $x_{a}$ $x\midscript{a}-$ $x^{x\midscript{a}-}$

x\textsuperscript{a} x\textsubscript{a} x\textmidscript{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the use of `\xvcenter{...}` in `\textmidscript` handle anything more robustly than `$\vcenter{...}$` does?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe something like this? (The trailing unary minus sign at the end of the first row is there just to demonstrate that the "middlescript letter" is aligned on the math-centerline.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mathmiddlescript[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}}}
\newcommand\textmiddlescript[1]{$\vcenter{\hbox{\scriptsize  #1}}$}

\begin{document}
$x^{a}$  $x_{a}$ $x\mathmiddlescript{a}-$ 

x\textsuperscript{a} x\textsubscript{a} x\textmiddlescript{a}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a significant difference between your succinct answer for inline text and the one proposed by @egreg in the comment above (`\def\textvcenter{\hbox \bgroup$\everyvbox{\everyvbox{}\aftergroup$\aftergroup\egroup}\vcenter}`)? I just wonder why the [TeX by Topic](http://www.math.ecnu.edu.cn/~latex/docs/Eng_doc/TeX_Topic.pdf "http://www.math.ecnu.edu.cn/~latex/docs/Eng_doc/TeX_Topic.pdf") author chose to publish the latter.

Comment: @kgo Eijkhout's macro allows `\setbox0=\textvcenter{...}`

Comment: @egreg - I couldn't have said it more succinctly. :-)

Comment: And `\setbox0` just hides text? So [Eijkhout's](http://www.math.ecnu.edu.cn/~latex/docs/Eng_doc/TeX_Topic.pdf "http://www.math.ecnu.edu.cn/~latex/docs/Eng_doc/TeX_Topic.pdf") solution just adds a hiding functionality to 'middletext'?