# Is there any special symbol to write "C++ programming"?

Tags: symbols

Is there any symbol to write

```
 C++ programming
```

I had tried:

```
$C++$
```

The output is a wide space.

Comment: Have you seen the posting [Prettiest way to typeset “C++” (cplusplus)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4302/5001)?

Comment: @Mico, thanks! You can delete my this question.

Comment: It's not a bad question at all, hence definitely no reason to delete it. However, it'll probably get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Wikipedia has an [svg symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#/media/File:ISO_C++_Logo.svg), which you could use.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Can you explain more what is the meaning of `can be use` is it a `Latex code`?

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2099) for a list of options. (Wikipedia also mentions that one should attribute the author.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Careful! The C++ logo is actually trademarked and copyrighted.  You can't use it without permission. https://isocpp.org/home/terms-of-use